# Is this sum differentiable w.r.t n?

Tags: derivatives

Let $T = \sum_{k=1}^n k^m$

Is T differentiable w.r.t $n$ ?

Comment: It's discrete in terms of n.

Comment: Why those downvotes ?

Comment: what's your idea of differentiation?

Comment: @YvesDaoust A bare question with no context whatsoever, which, as it is, makes as much sense as "Is the number zero purple?". Simply recalling the basic definition of differentiability yields either the answer "no" or "it's a meaningless question". If OP had at least shown that they knew what "differentiable" meant and why on Earth they would think that this could apply to a discrete function, I wouldn't have downvoted, but as it is...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I agree with that point of view, and it deserves to be explained to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the definition of differentiability with respect to some variable $V$ requires that the function is defined in some small neighborhood of the value of $V$ where you want to differentiate.
As your variable $n$ is probably supposed to be a natural number, this does not work immediately.

However, in some cases you might be able to assign to your $T$ a differentiable function. For example, in the case $m=1$, then $T=n(n+1)/2$ and you may extend this function of $n$ from the natural to the real numbers and define a derivative as usual.

Comment: There are tons and tons of smooth functions that extend this $T$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and the derivative at some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can literally be any real number.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi But there is only one such extension that is entire and has no essential singularity at infinity, so in these cases there is some best choice ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Do you sincerely think that OP even knows what an essential singularity is? It's even worse than these "Find the next number in the sequence" questions.

Comment: Indeed, my suggestion does not give a well-defined "derivative". But depending on what you want to do, there might be a "most reasonable" choice for the extension.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That may be true, but my comment merely makes an attempt at making "most reasonable" a mathematically sound concept. Then again, my method won't suffice to make $\Gamma$ the most reasonable interpolation of factorial ...